# Events perpetuity

Tags: event

Salesforce has the following maximum occurance limit when creating a recurring series of events:

o Daily: 100
o Weekly: 53
o Monthly: 60
o Yearly: 10

How can I create an event that last forever? Is there a way I can overcome this limit?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create non-related events, as the default recurrence mechanism ties all of the events together via a master event, which is why the limitations are in place. What you could do is create a schedulable class, and have that class run once a week to clone any events in the next week that have a certain flag set (I wouldn't recommend using the default salesforce.com fields for this). It would be a lot of work, but it's certainly feasible. Once the fields are added and the schedulable class written, you can schedule the class to run weekly via `System.schedule`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please explain me a bit more in detail how to do it? I'm new in Salesforce...do you have any sample code?

Comment: Unless something beats me to it, I'll try and write something up tonight.